# Android : how to execute AsyncTask?

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask

I have to load XML data in my app, I'm doing that in a subclass of my activity class extending AsyncTask like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Offre> listOffres;

    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>
    {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            listOffres = ContainerData.getFeeds();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_offres);

        DownloadXML.execute(); // Problem here !

        for(Offre offre : listOffres) { // etc }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to use execute() here, I have the following error :

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method execute(Integer...) 
>   from the type AsyncTask

I guess some parameters but what ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your `DonwloadXML` file and call `execute()` on that method:

```
DownloadXML task=new DownloadXML();
task.execute();
```

**EDIT:** you should probably also return the `listOffers` from your `doInBackground()` and process the array in the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsynTask`. You can have a look at this simple [AsyncTask tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 5):

you should call it like:

```
new DownloadXML().execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to execute some code by async task in **java** you can also do this:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // add code which you want to run in background thread

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // add code which you want to run in main(UI) thread
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

And in **kotlin** if you are using **anko**, there is much more simpler way to acheive this:

```
  doAsync {
            // add code which you want to run in background thread
            uiThread {
                // add code which you want to run in main(UI) thread
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to execute the UI code after the completion of the background work, Is there any callbacks available for that?

Comment: @MarGin Check this link: https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial
The order of execution of methods is: onPreExecute, doInBackground, onPostExecute.

 onPreExecute and onPostExecute runs on UI thread and doInBackground runs in bg thread.

Comment: @MarGin you should coroutines now if you are using kotlin that's the best

Comment: thanks for your quick response. can you please share any coroutine example for my purpose

Comment: You can check these references:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#0
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are calling the method of AsyncTask (which further extends the AsyncTask class) without making an OBJECT of that class.
you can call the execute method in two ways.

1. make an object/instance of the class like

   ```
   DownloadXML task=new DownloadXML();
   task.execute();
   ```
2. by using an flying object.

   ```
   new DownloadXML().execute();
   ```

I prefer to use here 2nd method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

u can execute ur asynctask either

```
new DownloadXML().execute();
```

or

```
 DownloadXML task=new DownloadXML();
 task.execute();
```

and one more thing u are getting in array in asynctask than it is good to use postexeceute method for ur for loop iteration

as given below

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    for(Offre offre : listOffres) { // do ur work here after feeling array }    


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object of DownloadXML class first.

```
DownloadXML downloadxml= new DownloadXML();
downloadxml.execute();
```

and return listOffres.

```
listOffres = ContainerData.getFeeds();
return listOffers;
```